# How can I get the following generator to work?

Tags: javascript, generator

As an experiment I want to create a generator that yields some integers with the following approximate design.

Can I get this to work (i.e. yielding from an inner function)?

```
function* numbers() { 
  [...Array(31)].forEach((_,i)=> {
      yield i; // Invalid syntax - how can this be changed?
  });
}

var generator = numbers();

for(var i of generator) {
    console.log(i); // I want 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7... to 30 to be printed
}
```

Comment: what result do you expect?

Comment: `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7.. to 30` to be printed to the console.

Comment: Right, sorry, I removed my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function* numbers() { 
  yield* Object.keys([...Array(31)])
}

var generator = numbers()

for(var i of generator) {
    console.log(i)
}
```

Comment: There was a typo on the original answer. Please take a look again.